# How to give different cell widths in pdf table in .net

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using itext sharp to generate table in PDF, but I want to give different cell widths as shown in image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iText for .Net is open source. Thus, one can simply look there and find this `PdfPTable` constructor

```
/** Constructs a <CODE>PdfPTable</CODE> with the relative column widths.
 * @param relativeWidths the relative column widths
 */
public PdfPTable(float[] relativeWidths)
{
    [...]
}
```

Thus, e.g.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] {2, 1});
```

should create a table with two columns, the first one being twice as wide as the second one.

To create a table as in your image the first visual column should consist of two columns, a small first and a larger second one. The "Totals" cell would be created with a colspan of two.